# Bathroom halachos in the bathroom

Tags: halacha, torah-study, bathroom

[One may not learn Torah in the bathroom.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/65659/9682) May one learn Torah that pertains to halachos of the bathroom that came up in the bathroom, or must one leave the bathroom, check the halachah, and return to the bathroom?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think it might be permitted. | If the prohibition is rooted in the disrespect to Torah, it would presumably be similarly disrespectful. | Are you specifically asking about laws that relate to a halakhic question at hand?

Comment: Just as an aside, Mas A"Z 44b has a related discussion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rama 85:2 brings down that it is not permitted to learn halachos of bathhouse in a bathhouse, so certainly learning bathroom halachos in the bathroom is prohibited  (Bathroom is more strict than a bathhouse)

אפילו להרהר בדברי תורה אסור בבית הכסא ובבית המרחץ ומקום הטינופת והוא המקום שיש בו צואה ומי רגלים.

הגה: ואפילו הלכות המרחץ אסור ללמוד במרחץ (ר"ן פרק כירה ובית יוסף בשם אורחות חיים).

Answer (score 3):

See  Magen Avraham  OC 84, sk 2:

> אם שאל לו אדם דבר הלכה אסור לומר לו "אין משיבין במרחץ". ובבית האמצעי שרי לומר כך. הרוצה לשתות בבית המרחץ יברך בחוץ ע"מ לשתות בפנים.‏
>
> If someone asks him Halacha in bathroom,  one is prohibited to answer: "It is prohibited to answer an halacha in bathroom!"  One can say this only at the average part of the bathroom in which some people are naked and some else are dressed  (Gemara Avoda  Zara  44b) .

So it seems that even halachot of the bathroom should not be said.

---

AZ 44b:

> Proclos, son of a philosopher, put a question to R' Gamaliel in Acco when the latter was bathing in the bath of aphrodite. He said to him, it is written in your torah, and there shall cleave nought of the devoted thing to thine hand; why are you bathing in the bath of Aphrodite? ' he replied to him, we may not answer [questions relating to torah] in a bath....
>
> GEMARA:
> But how did [R`Gamaliel] act in this manner?  ...     **A Tanna taught: When he came out, he replied to him, 'We may not answer [questions relating to Torah] in a bath'.**

We see the prohibition to teach hilchot bathroom in bathroom.

The words of the Magen Avraham is based on the words of RI in Tosfot AZ 44b (the first Tosfot of the page).

> `must one leave the bathroom, check the halachah, and return to the bathroom?`

**-->** Of course.

Regarding the status of modern bathroom versus Bet hamerchats in the times of Chachamim, see [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77811/9215) post.

Comment: After coming back to this post, I realize that this doesn't exactly answer the question. Halachos pertaining to the bathroom, sure. But halachos for which there is an immediate need to know the answer could possibly be permissible.

Comment: @DonielF immediate , you mean pikuach nefesh?

Comment: Not necessarily, but a shaalah which needs to be answered now.

Comment: @DonielF this is not the case of the Gemara?  I can think perhaps to a case of leafrushe meisura, which needs an immediate intervention, more than an explanation.

Comment: I'm in the bathroom, and there's something in the bathroom that needs to be done. Must I leave the bathroom to ask the shaaleh, or can I think about it in the bathroom? The case in Kol HaTzelamim did not need to be addressed in the bathroom.

Comment: @DonielF it is not the case of the Magen Avraham? He explains out of the bathroom the fact that it is prohibited to answer in the bathroom. It is an halacha concerning bathroom, no?

Comment: But it's not one that needs to be answered immediately. Say, for instance, someone needs to know about OC 3:10 (which hand to wipe with after). Can he think about that Halacha in the bathroom? (For argument's sake, let's say he's OCD and doesn't want to leave without wiping.)

Comment: @DonielF If you are asking about questions regarding a halakhic question at hand, edit that into the post. A clarification that was requested almost a year ago...No use complaining about posts not being what you want if you cant be bothered to write clear posts.

Comment: @mevaqesh I’m not sure what’s unclear about what I wrote, but I can try to rephrase it.